# Creating multiple subs on same topic to implement load sharing (pub/sub)

Tags: rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I spent almost a day on google pub sub documentation to create a small app. I am thinking of switching from rabbitMQ to google pub/sub. Here is my question:

I have an app that push messages to a topic (T). I wanted to do load sharing via subscribers. So I created 3 subscribers to T. I have kept the name of all 3 subs same (S), so that I don't get same message 3 times.

I have 2 issues:

1. There is no where I console I see 3 same subscribers to T. It shows 1
2. If I try to start all 3 instances of subscribers at same time. I get "A service error has occurred.". Error disappeared if I start in sequential manner.

Lastly, Is google serious about pub/sub ? Looking at the documentations and public participations, I am not sure if I should switch to google pub/sub.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

In pub/sub, each subscription gets a copy of every message. So to load balance handling message, you don't want 3 different subscriptions, but a single subscription that distributes messages to 3 workers.

If you are using pull delivery, simply create a single subscription (as a one-time action when you set up the system), and have each worker pull from the same subscription.

If you are using push delivery, have a single subscription pushing to a single endpoint that provides load balancing (e.g. push to a HTTP load balancer with multiple instances in a backend service

Google is serious about Pub/Sub, it is deeply integrated into many products (GCS, BigQuery, Dataflow, Stackdriver, Cloud Functions etc) and Google uses it internally.

Comment: hi, so far I have been unable to make something so seemingly simple work. If I create 3 subscribers with a message hanlder, even seeing them in the VM, only one message handler gets triggered. And when I use two VMs with their own subscriber, only one receives it. With Redis this works as expected. I suspect it has to do with the ack message, which seems to not only to not resend to one subscriber, but to any other. I'm still investigating, but documentation (for Java) is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation on GCP,https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture.

Load balanced subscribers are possible, but all of them have to use same subscription. Don't have any code sample or POC ready but working on same.